# Quotient algebra of tensor algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

There is the definition of exterior algebra over $R$-module $M$ as quotient algebra of tensor algebra:
$$\Lambda(M):= \frac{T(M)}{I}$$
Where $I$ is the ideal generated by $X=\{x_i\otimes x_i |x_i\in M\}$.

**First:** By definition, ideal $I$ of algebra $A$ must be a subalgebra of the algebra $A$. And when we say that ideal $I$ is generated by $X$, then also $X \subseteq A $.
Since tensor algebra $T(M)$ is a direct sum: $T(M)=\bigoplus\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}T^k_0M$, elements of $T(M)$ must be a sequences (by definition of direct sum): $T(M)\ni v = (v_0,v_1,v_2, \dots)$
Where $v_0 \in R$, $v_1 \in M$,$v_2 \in M \otimes M$, $\dots$ and $v_i=0$ for all but for finite number.

**Question:** How can we say about ideal $I$ generated by $X$ (as defined above) if $X$ is not even a subset of $T(M)$ since it's elements are not sequences? I agree that $X \subset M\otimes M = T^2_0M$,
 but $T^2_0M \not\subset T(M)$ since they have different cartesian products behind them.

Comment: You could define the polynomial algebra $k[x]$ as $\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty k x^i$, and then talk about the ideal generated by $x^2$. Do you see the similarity here with the tensor algebra?

Comment: Don't think as the direct sum as being a collection of sequences, but rather it being akin to the vector space generated by a collection of subspaces, so that every element is a sum of a finite number of elements from each $T_0^KM$.  Then $X$ is actually a subset of $T_0^2 M$.  If you still want to view this as a sequence, view it as a sequence where all but the second term are zero.

Comment: @Aaron I prefer to stick to the strict definitions of the objects I'm using, so for me elements of direct sum are elements of a cartesian product only.
So you say that: $X=\{(0_R,0_M,x_i \otimes x_i, 0_{M\otimes 3} , \dots)|x_i \in M\}$ should work?

Comment: @SergeyDylda Yes.  And for now, there is no harm in using the strict definitions, but there is value in having descriptions that are easier to use intuitively.  Essentially, to convert between sequences and sums, you are just breaking each sequence into its nonzero components and summing them, or taking a sum, identifying each summand as belonging to a unique $M_i$ in $\bigoplus M_i$, and then converting it to a sequence.  Eventually, you will prefer this notation (and because the conversion is so direct, it is just a matter of notation).

Comment: @Joppy Not quite. What's $x$ in your notation?
I know that polynomial ring R[X] is a free-R-module constructed from set X.
But how do you relate this to tensor algebra?

Comment: @SergeyDylda $R[x]\cong T(V)$ where $V$ is a one dimensional vector space.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, though I still do not understand what is $x$ Is it just one element from $V$?. Also, I don't want to use notation with sums because each slot of sequence needs to have his own $+_k$ as addition on correspondent $T^k M$ and then if you write the summ, you need to distinguish between all of those additions on different spaces, it confuses me a lot

Comment: @SergeyDylda Yes, the $x$ is any element of $V$.  And your point about needing multiple sums being confusing is well taken.